# Rule for primary key and foreign key in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I Have the folowing tables and columns

CAR

```
CarId   MarketId   Description
```

TIRE

```
TireId CarId MarketId Description
```

Primary keys as `CarId` and `TireId`.

Now I want to add a rule that check if foreign key `CarId` in `Tire` has the same `MarketId` in `Car`. Do I have to add a trigger or can it be done differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As CarID is unique in the `CAR` table, the combination CarID/MarketID will also be unique. So you can create a unique index on those two columns that can be the target of a foreign key constraint.

```
create table car 
(
  carid       integer not null primary key,
  marketid    integer not null,
  description varchar(100) not null
);

create unique index idx_car_market on car (carid, marketid);

create table tire
(
  tireid       integer not null primary key,
  carid        integer not null references car, -- this fk is not strictly necessary
  marketid     integer not null,
  description  varchar(100) not null  
);

alter table tire
   add constraint fk_tire_car 
   foreign key (carid, marketid)
   references car (carid, marketid);
```

The foreign key will ensure that only valid CarID/MarketID combinations are used in the tire table.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a car/tire cross-reference table and put the MarketId on that, instead of on the car and tire tables.  Then any given car/tire combination automatically has the same MarketId.

Of course, this is only a useful idea if you are in a position to change the table structure that much.